# Пересылается только последний байт из последовательности

Tags: android, arm, bluetooth

Всем добрый вечер!

Попал ко мне в руки этот Bluetooth-модуль HC-05. Подцепил я его к stm32vldiscovery по uart (использовал 1-й uart).
Ответная часть написана под Android по [этому мануалу](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).
Возникла проблема при попытке передачи элементарной последовательности «okay». Пробовал передать так:

```
void USART_PutSequence(uint8_t *sequence)
{
    while(*sequence != 0) {
        USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)*sequence);
        sequence++;
    }
}
```

Так:

```
void USART_PutSequence(uint8_t *sequence)
{
    USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)sequence[0]);
    USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)sequence[1]);
    USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)sequence[2]);
    USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)sequence[3]);
}
```

В любом случае приходит только «y», то есть последний байт. 
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Что-то не очень мне хочется передавать массивы побайтно, при этом синхронизируясь с задержками.

Comment: А логгер, что показывает - всю последовательность или только последнюю?

Comment: Только последнюю. Возникает предположение, что модуль по прерыванию с UARTа читает оттуда только один байт и пытается его передать. В это время приходит еще одно прерывание и так до конца последовательности. Но это больше на бред похоже - UART должен считываться до опустошения буфера...

Comment: Кстати, вот что. [тут][1] пишут, что соединение нужно перевести в режим COM-порт (правильно выразился?). Как это можно к андроиду интерпретировать?

1: http://robocraft.ru/blog/electronics/587.html

Comment: А тип uint8_t сколько занимает??? 8 байт или 8 бит?

Comment: Бит, конечно

Comment: странный uint конечно... У меня возникла версия, что занимает 8 байт - тогда все объясняется - проверь еще раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось в опросе бита Transmit Completed после посылки очередного байта:

```
void USART_PutSequence(uint8_t *sequence)
{
while(*sequence != 0) {
    USART_SendData(USART1, (uint8_t)*sequence);
    while (!(USART1->SR & USART_FLAG_TC));
}
}
```

Comment: Передавайте лучше массив через прерывания =) А вообще да, уарт небыстр и надо ждать окончания отправки.

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался с этим. Только вот, как использовать DMA я так и не понял. Приходится анализировать каждый пришедший байт - довольно накладно получается.

Comment: Это уже отдельный вопрос. Грубо говоря - говоришь ему, сколько байт копировать по какому событию, откуда и куда - вот он и копирует.

Comment: Это понятно. Но запускать же его, вроде, вручную надо. Вот я по прерыванию UARTa это и делаю, а в приемнике данных после этого нет...

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Прочитайте про DMA подробнее.